# Asp.net Identity: Erro no registro

Tags: asp.net-identity

Criei um projeto asp.net MVC com a autenticação "Individual User Accounts" e depois executei ele e fui tentar fazer um registro, porém foi lançada a seguinte exceção na linha 155:

```
Linha 154: var user = new ApplicationUser
                      {
                         UserName = model.Email, Email,
                         Email =   model.Email
                      };
Linha 155: var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

Mensagem:

> ```
> [SqlException (0x80131904): Erro de rede ou específico à instância ao estabelecer conexão com o SQL Server. O servidor não foi encontrado ou não estava acessível. Verifique se o nome da instância está correto e se o SQL Server está configurado para permitir conexões remotas. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Não é possível localizar uma instalação de Local Database Runtime. Verifique se o SQL Server Express está instalado corretamente e se o recurso Tempo de Execução de Banco de Dados Local está habilitado.)]
>    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling) +821
>    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +332
>    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +38
>    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +699
>    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +89
>    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +426
>    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
>    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +191
>    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +154
>    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +21
>    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +90
>    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +217
>    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
>    System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<Open>b__36(DbConnection t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c) +12
>    System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +72
>    System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +405
>    System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass33.<UsingConnection>b__32() +459
>    System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0() +15
>    System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +190
>    System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation) +82
>    System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +194
>    System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +603
>    System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CreateDatabaseFromScript(Nullable`1 commandTimeout, DbConnection sqlConnection, String createDatabaseScript) +87
>    System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection) +158
>    System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection) +73
>    System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateDatabase() +124
>    System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection connection) +112
>    System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase) +141
>    System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration) +79
>    System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext internalContext, Func`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext) +88
>    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateDatabase(ObjectContext objectContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +132
>    System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +215
>    System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +159
>    System.Data.Entity.Internal.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__e() +76
>    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +60
>    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +395
>    System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c) +11
>    System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +110
>    System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) +214
>    System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase() +97
>    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +28
>    System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +53
>    System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +16
>    System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() +39
>    System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate, CancellationToken cancellationToken) +154
>    System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) +163
>    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.<GetUserAggregateAsync>d__6c.MoveNext() +482
>    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
>    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
>    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() +59
>    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<ValidateUserName>d__4.MoveNext() +589
>    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
>    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
>    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<ValidateAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +293
>    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
>    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
>    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<CreateAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +558
>    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
>    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
>    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<CreateAsync>d__d.MoveNext() +550
>    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
>    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
>    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +28
>    IdentityTeste.Controllers.<Register>d__15.MoveNext() in D:\Informática\Raphael\Projetos VS2015\IdentityTeste\IdentityTeste\Controllers\AccountController.cs:155
>    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
>    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +97
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +17
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +50
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +225
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +26
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
>    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
>    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
>    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
>    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
>    System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9765121
>    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
> ```

Está dando esse erro mas quando entro no server [Meu-Server]\SQLEXPRESS com a Autenticação do Windows consigo acessar normalmente. Só da esse erro no ASP.NET Identity mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Qual é a sua **connection string**? Você não está a conectar-se ao servidor, mas só com o erro não dá para te ajudar. Edita a pergunta e adiciona o código da connection string.